# Placing collectionview contents horizontal left to right and right to left in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

I have an image like this:
[image: I have an image like this]

I have a partial code like this:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Country}" SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Flags">
            <Frame Margin="20,10" HeightRequest="122" Padding="0" HasShadow="True">
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                
                    <Image Source="{Binding FlagImage}" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="122" WidthRequest="122" Aspect="AspectFit" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding CountryName}"  Grid.Column="1"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" />
                    
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

My aim here is to display the frame content as in the image;
Arranging the first column from left to right, the second column from right to left. And it should continue like this.
Is there a way I can do this in xaml?

In the code I tried, I could only create the content from left to right.

Thank you in advance to those who will help.

Comment: Umm so what you want is once it should display the image on the left side and once on the right?

Comment: Yes exactly @FreakyAli

Comment: Having "upside down" in the title is misleading. The diagram and description indicate alternating between Image-Label and Label-Image horizontal layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best if you were using a [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-8.0#consume-a-datatemplateselector) ideally, all you will have to do is add a flag that tells you where to show the image, the easier way would be to share a boolean or a 1 or 0.

- Define a resource with your templates:

  ```
   <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="rightImage">
            <Grid>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="leftImage">
            <Grid>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:ImageTemplateSelector x:Key="imageDataTemplateSelector"
                                          RightTemplate="{StaticResource rightImage}"
                                          LeftTemplate="{StaticResource leftImage}" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
  ```
- Create a template selector:

  ```
  public class ImageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
  {
    public DataTemplate LeftTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate RightTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((YourModel)item).IsLeft ? LeftTemplate : RightTemplate;
    }
  }
  ```
- Then use it in your CollectionView:

  ```
   <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource imageDataTemplateSelector}" />
  ```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

FreakyAli's way definitely work, but I'd like to provide an other way to achieve this as well :

Instead of a Grid, you could use an HorizontalStackLayout with FlowDirection being RightToLeft or LeftToRight, and bind this FlowDirection to your item with a Converter, which will set FlowDirection according to if your item has an odd or even index in your Country collection :

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Flags">
    <Frame Margin="20,10" HeightRequest="122" Padding="0" HasShadow="True">
        <HorizontalStackLayout FlowDirection="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ItemToFlowDirectionConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourViewModelType, Path=Country}}}}">
            <Image Source="{Binding FlagImage}" HeightRequest="122" WidthRequest="122" Aspect="AspectFit" />
            <Label Text="{Binding CountryName}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" />    
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Frame>
</DataTemplate>
```

When calling the Converter, we give it as parameter your collection so the Converter can look inside for the index of your item.
The Converter code, don't forget to add it in the page's ResourceDictionary :

```cs
public class ItemToFlowDirectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // We check if our object and our parameter have the correct types
        if (object is Flags flag && parameter is List<Flags> flagsCollection)
        {
            int indexOfFlag = flagsCollection.FindIndex(x => x == flag);
            // Only even-index elements are aligned from left to right
            if (indexOfFlag == -1 || indexOfFlag%2 == 0) return "LeftToRight";
            return "RightToLeft";
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[More infos on Converters.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters?view=net-maui-8.0)

Comment: I thought flow direction was supposed to be used when you need to change your language and the language has a different flow direction like Arabic or Hebrew, Also this won't work on iOS https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8556

Comment: I don't know if it ls meant for language support or not, but it actually works for flow direction in stacklayouts as well. Didn't know about this iOS bug tho

Comment: Np brother all I'm saying is your solution is kind of a workaround but I support the effort so an upvote from me ❤️